# What is wrong with these attempts at a batch file to export my Excel 2003 recent file list?

Tags: microsoft-excel, batch-file, windows-registry

What is wrong with these attempts at a batch file to export my Excel 2003 recent file list?

I keep getting either syntax errors or an error saying that the specified registry key cannot be found. Here are the variations I've tested:

```
REG EXPORT HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Excel\"Recent Files" C:\users\Murray\Desktop\Tools\"Restore Excel Recent Files New.reg" /y /reg:64

REG EXPORT HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Excel\Recent Files\ C:\users\Murray\Desktop\Tools\"Restore Excel Recent Files New.reg" /y /reg:64

REG EXPORT "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Excel\Recent Files\" C:\users\Murray\Desktop\Tools\"Restore Excel Recent Files New.reg" /y /reg:64
```

Here is a copy of a recent export I've done manually using regedit:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
```

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Excel\Recent Files] "File1"="C:\Users\Murray\Documents\EXCEL\PERSONAL\Brookline\Oil.xls" "File2"="C:\Users\Murray\Desktop\Tools\Trading Log.xls" "File3"="C:\Users\Murray\Documents\EXCEL\PERSONAL\Elliott Wave\FCX.xls" "File4"="C:\Users\Murray\Documents\EXCEL\PERSONAL\Elliott Wave\TLT.xls" "File5"="C:\Users\Murray\Documents\EXCEL\PERSONAL\FCPeuro Orders.xls" "File6"="C:\Users\Murray\Documents\EXCEL\PERSONAL\540_Maintenance.xls" "File7"="C:\Users\Murray\Documents\EXCEL\PERSONAL\Quechee\Propane.xls" "File8"="C:\Users\Murray\Documents\EXCEL\PERSONAL\Suzemax Rates.xls" "File9"="C:\Users\Murray\Documents\EXCEL\PERSONAL\Med19.xls"

The point being the key is located at:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Excel\Recent Files]
```

I have a Win 10 64 Home laptop. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Use the 3rd one and remove the ``\`` after `Files` - `REG EXPORT "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Excel\Recent Files" ...`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
REG EXPORT "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Excel\Recent Files" "C:\users\Murray\Desktop\Tools\Restore Excel Recent Files New.reg" /y /reg:64
```

When you have spaces in the key's name, pathname, etc., it is safer to enclose it/them between double-quotes.